# What were the practices observance of which was abhorred by St Paul in Gal 4:9-10?

Tags: tradition, feasts, galatians, pagan

In Galatians 4:9-10 we see St Paul sending a terse message to the faithful abhorring their observance of days, months, seasons and years terming them weak and beggarly elements. Unfortunately, he does not specify what those elements are. In fact, Jewish traditions mandated the observance of feasts and spells of prayer, determined by the days, seasons etc. Jesus followed them . Evidently, St Paul was referring to something else. My question therefore is ; what were the practices observance of which was abhorred by St Paul in Gal 4:9-10 ? Inputs from scholars of any denomination are welcome.

Comment: There is no evidence in scripture that Jesus 'followed' the various feasts. Yes he participated. Yes he was present. But he, himself, was the fulfillment of them all. He did not 'follow' them. His presence terminated them. For ever.

Comment: @NigelJ In my mind, participating in a feast is the definition of "following" a feast. Can you clarify what you mean by "following" a feast if it is not participation?

Comment: @THummus The feasts "followed" Jesus, more than the other way around. They pointed to him; and those who observed them in faith saluted him from afar.

Comment: I understand the phrase "follow a feast" to mean "act according to the customs of a feast". I would say that Jesus certainly did act according to the customs of the Jewish feasts. It is true that he was the point of the feasts, and it's also true that he fulfilled and ended the feasts. But that doesn't mean that he didn't also act according to those traditions. So I guess I take issue with the assertion that Jesus did not follow the feasts. But I suppose we just mean different things by the word "follow"

Comment: It is important (the matter of 'following') as this is exactly what Paul is determining : the slavish following of outward ritual at the expense of the reality of the fulfillment of the reason the ritual was given in the first place - to draw attention to the everlasting gospel and the everlasting testament, both of which are fulfilled by the coming of Christ, which event nullifies the ritual and makes the ritual redundant.

Answer (score 6):

The practices being observed by Galatian Christians, which Paul so abhorred he wrote in the strongest terms to dissuade them from doing, were those things back then causing them to return to bondage. That is what the end of verse 9 states.

This means that ***they had stopped doing some things after Christ had set them free, but now they were going back to those practices***, not realising that that was jeopardizing their freedom in Christ, getting them back into bondage.

**This is about spiritual bondage**. From the start of chapter 3 Paul asks the Galatians (whom he calls 'foolish') who has bewitched them into no longer obeying the truth. He says they had begun in the Spirit (being made spiritual sons of God, through faith in Christ), but now they were seeking to be made perfect by the flesh (verse 3). So, there's what Paul is distressed about - they are now seeking to be "made perfect by the flesh" instead of by the Spirit. Some people were persuading them that they still needed to keep the (Mosaic) law to be justified. Paul categorically told them "that no man is justified by the law in the sight of God, it is evident, for 'The just shall live by faith'." (verse 11) He pointed out that Abraham was accounted righteous by faith - before the law was given.

When the law was given later, it was to show God's people that they would be cursed if they did not keep everything in it. Now Christ had come and redeemed them from the curse of the law (verse 13),

> "that the blessing of Abraham might come on the Gentiles through Jesus
> Christ: that we might receive the promise of the Spirit through
> faith." Galatians 3:14 A.V.

Paul then reminded them in chapter 4 that they had been in bondage under the law. But now the time had come to receive the adoption as God's son, proof of this spiritual transformation being the giving of the Spirit to them, so that they could now cry to God, "Abba! Father!" (verses 6 & 7).

But now they were turning back to some observances that they had been freed from. In their case, it happened to be religious observance of certain days, months, times and years. He does not mention circumcision, so it wasn't that in their case (though it had been with some others who would be bound to keep the law if they became circumcised.) No, they were binding themselves to a religious calendar of events. He does not spell out the details of those events because they would be well known to both him and them.

To apply this practically, to ourselves in this day and age, a letter rebuking modern-day Christians for returning to "weak and miserable elements" could be anything that makes us trust in something that we used to do that we thought was a legal requirement for getting (or staying) right with God. There are, for example, lots of superstitions some religious people think are important to observe. Or there are particular 'holy days' they must devote themselves to keeping the right way to keep 'on course' with God. Compared with the glorious spiritual freedom in Christ Christians are given freely, those would be "weak and miserable elements". That is why Paul goes on to explain the allegory of the free woman, Sarah, and the bond-woman, Hagar. Christians are children of the free woman (verse 31), so why on earth would they want to turn to bondage again? Why on earth would they start doing worldly 'spiritual' things that were in opposition to the spiritual miracle of grace that had made them free sons of God, in Christ?

So, **the answer to the question is that they were those things that would chain them to the law, stopping them from walking in the freedom of faith in Christ. In our case it might be something different.** We are to examine ourselves to ***make sure we never get into a worldly system of doing (or believing) things that undermine or outrightly attack our freedom in Christ.*** This was purchased for us at great cost, though freely given to us. Yet once set free, we should devote, and even be prepared to give, our lives for the One who liberated us - Christ.

Answer (score 4):

It wasn't the practices per se, it was the goal the people were attempting to get to of the practices that Paul abhorred.  Galatians is full of the contrast between the Mosaic Law and Grace in Christ.

To understand Paul's point, we need to understand the point of the Mosaic Law.

> And it [the whole of the Mosaic Law] shall be our righteousness, if we observe to do all these commandments before the LORD our God, as he hath commanded us. Deut 6:25

Yes, Christ came to fulfill the Law, not destroy it.  And in its fulfilling, Christ became our righteousness by grace through faith.

> And be found in him, not having mine own righteousness, which is of the law, but that which is through the faith of Christ, the righteousness which is of God by faith: Phil 3:9

Galatians is full of the contrast between grace and works.  Paul's prime example is the two women metaphor between Agar/Sinai/Law and Isaac/Zion/Grace.  Grace saves, doing what the Law could not.

Some of those in Galatia failed to understand this.

> But now, after that ye have known God, or rather are known of God, how turn ye again to the weak and beggarly elements, whereunto ye desire again to be in bondage? Gal 4:9

The word "beggarly" is ptochos, to beg, hide, or cower.  See Vines, Strongs, etc.

> Ye observe days, and months, and times, and years. Gal 4:10

The word "observe" is paratereo, "translated "ye observe" in Gal 4:10, where the Middle Voice suggests that their religious observance of days, etc. was not from disinterested motives, but with a view to their own advantage." [Vines here.](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g3906/kjv/tr/0-1/)

In other words, they were carefully observing certain times with a view not to honor God, but as beggars to perchance be saved from their sins.

> Let us therefore come boldly unto the throne of grace, that we may obtain mercy, and find grace to help in time of need. Heb 4:16

Christians observe Easter, Christmas, and other times.  Why?  To cower because they doubt their salvation or to boldly enter the throne of grace?

Comment: I know Mosaic Law is in view in other areas of Galatians but doesn't verse 8 indicate that the Galatians were returning to the beggarly elements of pagan worship here?

Comment: It would include pagan converts, but it is also about Jewish converts.  Gal 4:5 is about those under the law, plus perhaps a nod to Romans 2:14.  Gal 4:8 expands to include not knowing God, which would be both Jew and Gentile (gotta believe in His Son).  Recall the Golden Calf or 1 King 9:6, Jer 11:10, 44:3, etc.  V9 then returns to the times/seasons used as a means for their righteousness., rather than grace by faith. 
 Who's the heir of Gal 4:1?  Those saved by grace.

Comment: @MikeBorden It's kinda confusing. Verse 8 does suggest it's talking about pagan feast days. But, as you follow Paul's argument, he brings up "following the law" in verse 21. It wouldn't surprise me if Paul is referencing some pagan holidays, but is actually concerned that they are turning to follow Jewish holidays--i.e., that they are becoming Judaized. Paul was very much against the idea that Gentile Christians had to convert to Judaism, and follow the Jewish laws.

Comment: @trlkly Or Paul considers observance of any religious 'laws' which attempt to buttress what Christ has done or increase either our access to Christ or our righteousness in Christ as actually a departure from the gospel.  It could be confusing because Mosaic law and Pagan religious practice are seen through the same lens in Galatians.